# Declaring variable in a FOR one time

Tags: java

I have a simple question in java. I have this piece of code:

```
int i1=0;
for(String x: list1)
{
    for(String y: list2)
    {

        if(x == y)
        {
            log ("Checking "+x+" with "+y+" => found a match!");
            list1.remove(i1);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            log ("Checking "+x+" with "+y+" => not matching!");
        }
    }
    i1=i1+1;
}
```

As u can see, i'm declaring **"i1"** above, but is there a way to declare it in the first for just once and after the finish of that **FOR** to unset itself?

Hope you understand me.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to recreate the functionality of `removeAll(Collection c)`. You're also incorrectly comparing the `String` values.

Comment: any specific reason to have i1 incremented only once.

Comment: just declare it in the block of the for.

Comment: Is it me or is there something missing here? I don't see anything modifying the value of i1, it's just 0 all the time and it's passed to remove().
edit: this is weird, "i1=i1+1;" wasn't there when I first opened this page.

Comment: No, I don't understand. Do you want to limit the scope of `i1` to the outermost `for`-loop?

Comment: @adnan: there's now an `i1=i1+1` near the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Sure, wrap the whole thing in a block. What's the point, though?

Comment: i1 must live only in that FOR-loop, because i have like 10 for-s and i get duplicate variables and i have to put them i1 i2 i3 i4 ....

Comment: I still don't get what you want, if you want to only use a variable i, just put the whole code section in a block { }

Comment: i know, but this **for(String x: list1)** that is looking like a foreach from PHP won't have an **i** ...

Comment: You have 10 for loops in one method? I daresay we found your first problem.

Comment: just try to copy/paste that once, and you will have to rename the second **i1** to **i2**

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that in Java. If you move the declaration inside the `for` loop, then the variable will be reassigned to its initial value on every iteration through the loop.

If by "unset" you mean "go out of scope", you probably don't really need to worry about that; there are no performance issues there. If you *really* want to force the variable to go out of scope at the end of your outer `for` loop, you could create an extra block around the whole thing, like this (but you really don't need to do this, it's unnecessary!):

```
{ // Beginning of block <----------
    int i1=0;
    for(String x: list1)
    {
        for(String y: list2)
        {

            if(x == y)
            {
                log ("Checking "+x+" with "+y+" => found a match!");
                list1.remove(i1);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                log ("Checking "+x+" with "+y+" => not matching!");
            }
        }
        i1=i1+1;
    }
} // End of block <----------
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i get duplicate variable when i copy/paste this for once again, and i go like i2 i3 i5 i654546

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can write the code like this:

```
for(String x = list1.get(0), int i1 = 0; i1 < list1.size(); 
                                     i1++, x = list1.get(i1) )
{
    for(String y: list2)
    {

        if(x == y)
        {
            log ("Checking "+x+" with "+y+" => found a match!");
            list1.remove(i1);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            log ("Checking "+x+" with "+y+" => not matching!");
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm wrong please warn me.

Comment: `list1` is a `Collection`, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java expert, but I remember something about not remove objects from a list while you iterate it.

So (even if I'm wrong), you should do something like this:

```
for(int i1=0;i<list1.size();i1++)
{
    String x=list1.get(i1);
    for(String y: list2)
    {

        if(x == y)
        {
            log ("Checking "+x+" with "+y+" => found a match!");
            list1.remove(i1--);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            log ("Checking "+x+" with "+y+" => not matching!");
        }
    }
}
```

don't forget the `--` in the remove!